# How do I add plus 1 to a string that is composed of numbers

Tags: javascript

Scenario: I have some strings that I need to increment the numeric value by 1 without losing anything in the string.

```
Example strings:
"000000" should equal to "000001"
"000100" should equal to "000101"
"000009" should equal to "000010"
```

I tried some things, looping to each characters starting at the end but there are some cases that its wrong. I thought there might be a better way of doing it.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) can be used to pad with characters to a certain length

```js
str="000000"

console.log(
`${+str+1}`.padStart(str.length,'0')
)

str="000000010"

console.log(
`${+str+1}`.padStart(str.length,'0')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `padStart()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

```js
/*
"000000" should equal to "000001"
"000100" should equal to "000101"
"000009" should equal to "000010"
*/

const a = "000000";
const b = "000100";
const c = "000009";


console.log((Number(a)+1).toString().padStart(6,"0"));
console.log((Number(b)+1).toString().padStart(6,"0"));
console.log((Number(c)+1).toString().padStart(6,"0"));
```